# PHP: simple_html_dom - how to find elements that are NOT in a certain class?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm using simple_html_dom in PHP to get all A-tags inside a html page. But some tags are inside a div that should be ignored.

I guess I need something like :

`$htmldom->find("!div[class=blabla] a");`

I found that I can use `[attribute!=value]` to specify elements that do NOT have a certain attribute value, but how would this work for elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically had it:

```
$htmldom->find("[class!=blabla] a");
```

Comment: Thanx... but doesn't this require all valid a's to be inside a DIV ?  Maybe there is something like a wildcard (instead of DIV) to match any element ??

Comment: @Dylan - You can just leave out the div selector then, (or use the * character).